# Meaning of # in a java class path

Tags: java, class

Below is a class path. What is the meaning of the `#` in the class path?

```
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.star.StarGraph#StarVertex
```

The above is a class in `tinkerpop` library.

Comment: StarVertex is an inner class of StarGraph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The # symbol is used with inner classes. In this instance StarVertex is an inner class of StarGraph

Comment: Shouldn't it be a `$`?